# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, phpmyadmin

I want to create a dynamic menu, with sub menus.
Will be Level1, Level2, Level3.

But I get this error:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many()
and 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs****\resources\views\test.blade.php)

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class WorkoutLevel1 extends Model
{
    protected $table ='workout_level1s';

    protected $fillable = ['title','icon','order_no'];

    public function workoutlvl2(){
         return $this->has_many('WorkoutLevel2');
      }
}`
```

`

```
<?php
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class WorkoutLevel2 extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'workout_level2s';

   public function workoutlvl1(){
         return $this->belongs_to('WorkoutLevel1');
      }

   public function workoutlvl3(){
        return $this->has_many('WorkoutLeve3');
   }   

   protected $fillable = ['title','order_no'];
}
```

`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WorkoutLevel3 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'workout_level3s';

    public function workoutlvl2(){
         return $this->belongs_to('WorkoutLevel2');
      }

    protected $fillable = ['title','order_no'];
}
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/menu', function () {
    $lvl1s = App\WorkoutLevel1::all();

    return View::make('test',compact('lvl1s'));
});`
```

The view `

```
<div class="categories">
            <!-- // left menu.... -->
            <ul class="main">
                @foreach($lvl1s as $lvl1)
                    <li><a href="">{{$lvl1->title}}</a></li>
                    @foreach($lvl1->workoutlvl2->take(2) as $lvl2)
                        <li><a href="">{{$lvl2->title}}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many()

So, replace `has_many` with `hasMany` (and `belongs_to` with `belongsTo`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't pay attention. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel 5 use `hasMany` and `belongsTo` instead of `has_many`.
You can also check Laravel docs.

Answer (score 0):

evenn in laravel 4.2 it's not has_many, the correct usage is hasMany...